# Show date slicer values in long date format

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to show the long date format in the date slicer? Instead of how the values are displayed in the picture below, I want the slicer value to be in the 'dd/mon/yyyy' format.

e.g 4-Jan-2021  25-Apr-2023

[image]

Comment: Please show actual code of what you have tried and your one challenge with that so we may best assist you here.

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/date-format-in-slicer/m-p/215627